# Referencing Dictionary Values in Bottle.py App

Tags: python, html, dictionary, bottle

I have written an HTML code that involves people choosing values from multiple drop-down boxes. These drop-down values are names, that have values associated with them located in a dictionary. What I am trying to do is when the submit button is hit on the form, my program will choose the values associated with each name that the user has chosen, and plug those values into the equation. The part I'm stuck on is referencing those values from the dictionary.

Currently, what I have is

from bottle import request

1lw = request.forms.get("1lw")

I know this will get the name from the drop down box with the id "1lw." How can I use that name and equate it to the value associated with it in the dictionary?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `name = request.form.get('1|w')` to get the name and then `values = your_dict[name]` to get the associated values ?

Comment: okay, let me make sure i understand that. so your_dict[name] would be calling the value associated with that name, and values would just be setting it equal to a variable named values?